# MongoDB Aggregation Framework: Why do I have to use unwind? Why isn't there a $count?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm a bit confused on MongoDB's aggregation framework.

In order to do distinct counts of a specific field, I have to use the `$addToSet` operator, then `$unwind`, then `$group` with a `$sum`

What I'm not getting is why Mongo doesn't have a $count operator to just count the length of the array (instead of using `$unwind` and doing all the other steps)

What I'm doing now is just counting the length of the array in my driver, but technically my driver is having to download all the extra data.

Is there any reason why there isn't a `$count` or a `$countUnique` operator? Or is there some way to do this already with Mongo that I'm just not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

Upcoming 2.6 version adds a new operator `$size` which will give you the size of the array and can be used in `$project` stage after the `$group` with `$addToSet` to get the number you want.

References:

http://docs.mongodb.org/master/release-notes/2.6/#aggregation-enhancements
http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#exp._S_size

Comment: not for very long - 2.6.0 release candidate 2 has been out for a week.